# Setup the Correct Path of elFinder for Web Hosting (IIS 7+)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elfinder

i have used `elFiner` in my project (with elFinder Connector) and works great on localhost.
But when i deploy it to the server (online hosting), It gives me an error `target dir not found or access denied`. here is my configuration;

```
  <elFinder apiVersion="2.0"
            localFSRootDirectoryPath="D:\Projects\Emaar\Emaar.Web\Areas\EmaarAdmin\Content\images"
            localFSThumbsDirectoryPath="D:\Projects\Emaar\Emaar.Web\Areas\EmaarAdmin\Content\images\.thumbs"
            rootDirectoryName="Root"
            uploadMaxSize="20M"
            defaultVolumeName="LocalFileSystem"
            baseUrl="http://localhost:4595/Areas/EmaarAdmin/Content/images/"
            baseThumbsUrl="http://localhost:4595/Areas/EmaarAdmin/Content/images/.thumbs/"  
            duplicateFilePattern="Copy of {0}"
            duplicateDirectoryPattern="Copy of {0}"
            thumbsSize="48,48">
  </elFinder>
```

I believe my path aren't correct in my web.config. 
**How do i setup the `elFinder` to work also online (on the web)?** 
**UPDATE:** my online settings looks like this;

```
    <elFinder apiVersion="2.0" localFSRootDirectoryPath="\Areas\EmaarAdmin\Content"
localFSThumbsDirectoryPath="\Areas\EmaarAdmin\Content\.thumbs" 
rootDirectoryName="Root Main" uploadMaxSize="20M" defaultVolumeName="LocalFileSystem" 
baseUrl="http://subdomain.domain.com/Areas/EmaarAdmin/Content/"
baseThumbsUrl="http://subdomain.domain.com/Areas/EmaarAdmin/Content/.thumbs/"
duplicateFilePattern="Copy of {0}" duplicateDirectoryPattern="Copy of {0}" thumbsSize="48,48">
```

i have also set the permission to `Read` and `Write`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem by doing a simple trick. First i have wrote the following code and put it inside the `_Layout` (razor) file.

```
@HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```

This gave me a physical path and then i just copied it and paste it inside the `localFSRootDirectoryPath` and `localFSThumbsDirectoryPath` and it did work